# Buttons of Structure Properties window in Eclipse does not working

Tags: android, eclipse, button, layout, interface

A have a problem with Eclipse. I can't press "..." buttons in Structure Properties window of layout editor (Padding, Gravity, Background, etc.).
When i click on them, they look pressed, but nothing happens
How can i fix this?
Thanks.

Comment: Yes, Android layout editor

Comment: So.. does anybody have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved by deleting Android 4.4 sdk